# How to fix issue when committing a change to CVS

Tags: cvs, commit, conflict

I'm trying to commit my changes to CVS repository, but I get the following error:

```
RCS file: /opt/CZarmen/CVS_REPOSITORY/Z_user/lib/python/StudioCustom.py,v
retrieving revision 1.38
retrieving revision 1.39
Merging differences between 1.38 and 1.39 into StudioCustom.py
M lib/python/StudioCustom.py

RCS file: /opt/CZarmen/CVS_REPOSITORY/Z_user/menu_scripts/Y/ZExtensions,v
retrieving revision 1.46
retrieving revision 1.47
Merging differences between 1.46 and 1.47 into ZExtensions
M menu_scripts/Y/ZExtensions

cvs commit: Up-to-date check failed for `lib/python/StudioCustom.py'
cvs commit: Up-to-date check failed for `menu_scripts/Y/ZExtensions'
cvs [commit aborted]: correct above errors first!
```

Why does it fail to commit my changes? How do I "correct above errors"?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to update your working copy first by running `cvs up` because someone has already updated these files while you were working on them. CVS can't automatically merge these changes during commit.

Comment: But if I update my working copy, I will lose my edits, won't I? I mean, say the file contains "abc", I want to make it "abcd", but someone has already updated it to "abce". If I update my working copy, my file will be "abce", and "abcd" will be lost, Right?

Comment: And, which one is the "working copy"? The one in CVS repositry, or the one in my local computer?

Comment: The working copy is your directory in which you want to do the `cvs commit` call. The server part is called repository. `cvs update` will not overwrite your changes (unless you pass the `-C` flag), but if you're worried you can first do `cvs diff >myChanges.patch` to save your modifications in a patch.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, just in case you may get error sometimes to UPDATE your local version. The final solution is :

> **1. Save your local code to another place manually**
>
> **2. Revert the files which may have conflicts to the HEAD (most latest) version on CVS server.**
>
> **3. Add back your change to the Reverted file.**

The concept for above solution is to CLEAR UP all the possible issue by REVERT and get a 100% clean version from the repository then add back our changes.

It can resolve below issues which caused by code out of date / code base messed up.

> 1. CVS commit had a conflict and has not been modified
> 2. CVS update failed
> 3. CVS not synced